# Dictionary from array of keys and items

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of array of strings

```
{
"items": [
["Jack", 24, "California"], ["Roman", 26, "Pittsburg"], ["Rebecca", 22, "Israel"]
],
"keys":["name", "age", "place"]
}
```

I need to convert it into a array of dictionary so that I can map it to my model class like this

```
{
"items":[
{
"name": "Jack",
"age": 24,
"place": "California"
},
{
"name": "Roman",
"age": 26,
"place": "Pittsburg"
},
{
"name": "Rebecca",
"age": 22,
"place": "Israel"
}
]
}
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Why this extra step? Map them directly to your custom class instead and if you need some help on that then first try to solve it yourself and include the code you have an issue with. Btw, is this json? Then you should look into using Codable.

Comment: How can I map my array to Codable of objects?

Comment: By doing some research, this is not a code writing service. There are a multitude of articles and tutorials on the subject  to be found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Dictionary` is,

```
let dict = [
    "items": [["Jack", 24, "California"], ["Roman", 26, "Pittsburg"], ["Rebecca", 22, "Israel"]],
    "keys":["name", "age", "place"]
]
```

**Approach-1**

Use **`map(_:)`** to get the expected result.

```
if let items = dict["items"] as? [[Any]], let keys = dict["keys"] as? [String] {
    let result = items.map {(arr) -> [String:Any] in
        var temp = [String:Any]()
        for (i, item) in arr.enumerated() {
            temp[keys[i]] = item
        }
        return temp
    }
    print(result)
}
```

**Approach-2**

Also, you can use **`map(_:)`**, **`zip(_:_:)`** and **`forEach(_:)`** to get the expected `result`.

```
if let items = dict["items"] as? [[Any]], let keys = dict["keys"] as? [String] {
    let result = items.map {(arr) -> [String:Any] in
        var dict = [String:Any]()
        let x = zip(keys, arr).forEach({ dict[$0.0] = $0.1 })
        return dict
    }
    print(result)
}
```